# jQuery: Add and remove a <br> tag depending on window width and whether or not tag already exists

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to use jQuery to:

- check the document width on loading the page AND
- check the document width when the user resizes the page.

After checking:

- if the document width is greater than 2400px AND the tag with id "lineBreak" doesn't exist, I want to add the "lineBreak" tag in after "#container-3".
- if the document width is less than 2400px and the "lineBreak" tag already exists, I want to remove it from the DOM.

My code isn't working - doesn't seem to do anything at all at present... No errors in the console to diagnose the issue with. Furthermore, I suspect there's a simpler way to achieve the desired results.

Many thanks in advance for help fixing this.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var windowWidth = $(window).width();
var lineBreakLength = $('#lineBreak').length;
if (windowWidth >= 2400 && lineBreakLength == 0) {
    $('#container-3').after('<br id="lineBreak">');
    console.log('Window width greater than 2400px. Added <br> tag.');
} else if (windowWidth < 2400 && lineBreakLength > 0) {
    $('#lineBreak').remove();
    console.log('Window width less than 2400px. Removed <br> tag.');
}
});

$(window).resize(function() {
var windowWidth = $(window).width();
var lineBreakLength = $('#lineBreak').length;
if (windowWidth >= 2400 && lineBreakLength == 0) {
    $('#container-3').after('<br id="lineBreak">');
    console.log('Window width greater than 2400px. Added <br> tag.');
} else if (windowWidth < 2400 && lineBreakLength > 0) {
    $('#lineBreak').remove();
    console.log('Window width less than 2400px. Removed <br> tag.');
}
});
```

Comment: Why can't you simply use media queries to show/hide the break at 2400px?

Comment: What @Scott said. Plus, maybe it doesn't even need a `br` element - switching from floating or inline-block (or whatever makes your divs be displayed next to each other in the first place) to non-floating/block might be enough already.

Comment: Do yourself a favor, if you have the same code in two places, make it a function.

Comment: Good point... thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 2400px)  {
   .break {display:none;}
}
```

now in your html:

```
<br class="break" />
```

Here is the [**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/kjk1tL7c/)

Note that in the demo for easy testing I have changed 2400 to 600

However if you insist on doing it by jQuery(which is not recommended):

```
if($(document).width() <=2400)
     $('.break').css('display','block');
else 
     $('.break').css('display','none');
```

Comment: Wow - so easy when you know how! Many thanks Ashkan.

Comment: Just one little point on this - just implemented the code and I think "min-width" should be "max-width" for the purposes of the original question; so:

`@media only screen and (max-width: 2400px)  {
   .break {display:none;}
}`

because this will _hide_ the <br> tag when the document width is less than 2400px, and _show_ it when it's wider than that.